# Signing a package with Apple configurator 2 + ssl cert

Tags: apple-configurator

I downloaded apple configurator, and I made a profile with a webclip of my site. I have purchased ssl certs for my site and have verified they are working.

My problem is - the package says it's not signed when being installed on phones. How do I sign the package so that its verified by my certs on my site?

I could really use help!